# Refreshing variable when clicking on link

Tags: php, variables

Hello i got variable $offset. When user is viewing page - $offset should be equal to 0;

When he is clicking on link

```
<a href="players.php?next=3">Next</a>
```

It should update the $offset by adding to it next's value.

So i wrote like this

```
$offset = $offset + $_GET['next'];
```

When i'm clicking on link first time it works, but the future clicks doesnt, because he dont remember $offset value. How should i write to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would deplore using a session to store this. It is a waste of server resources.

```
$nextLot=3;
$offset=0;
if(!empty($_GET['offset']))
{
    $offset=$_GET['offset'];
}
$offset+=$_GET['next'];

<a href="players.php?offset=<?php=$offset?>&next=<?php=$nextLot?>">Next</a>
```

This method saves some resources and simply checks the URL for all the info that is needed.

Comment: @DipeshParmar All good, but you didn't have to delete your answer, I just didn't think it was the most efficient way of doing it. It might well help others do something similar that can't be done via a URL or POST data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `SESSION`

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['next']) : ?>
  <a href="players.php?next=<?php echo $_SESSION['next']; ?>">Next</a>
<?php else : ?>
  <a href="players.php?next=1">Next</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and for `offset`

```
$_SESSION['offset'] = isset($_SESSION['offset']) + $_GET['next'];
```

Comment: It'll work, but sessions to store what the offset is? Don't you think that is wasteful?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the $offset variable via $_SESSION.

So your code will look something like this:

```
$_SESSION['offset'] = $_SESSION['offset'] + $_GET['next'];
```